# Wordpress return selected values by using Advanced Custom Fields Relations

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have a custom field which is a selectbox and the type is of Relation. I filter the relation by posts and now I want to display the selected posts on a specific page:

here is my query:

```
$ids = get_field('choose_cars', false, false); // name of the select box

$query = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type'         => 'cars', // is my custom post type
    'posts_per_page'    => 3,
    'post__in'          => $ids,
    'post_status'       => 'publish',
    'orderby'           => 'post__in',
));

$query = new WP_Query($args);

 if($query->have_posts()) {
    while($query->have_posts() ){
        $query->the_post();
        ?>

    <?php $image = get_field('car_image'); ?>
    <div>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
            <div class="car-wrapper" style="position: relative;">
                <div class="car-image" style="background-image:url('<?php echo $image['url']; ?>')"></div>
                <div class="overlay">
                    <div class="content">
                            <p><?= get_field('car_name') ?></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
    <?php }
}
die();
```

Nothing happens, so maybe someone can tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Is this code on the post with the field you're trying to read? If not, the second argument of `get_field()`should be the post ID of the post which has this data. If you don't pass one or set it as false as you have then ACF will try to get the data from the current post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ignore my comment (although it's always worth pointing out) the problem is that you're defining `$query` and then immediately overwriting it

```
$query = new WP_Query(array(...));

$query = new WP_Query($args);
```

So, change the first one to

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'         => 'cars', // is my custom post type
    'posts_per_page'    => 3,
    'post__in'          => $ids,
    'post_status'       => 'publish',
    'orderby'           => 'post__in',
);
```

and it should work (assuming this is the post with the field data as per my comment!)